# How to scale a movie clip in flash with buttons on top of it

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, actionscript, flash-builder

my question is:
Is there a way to fix a button's position in flash, in relation to a movie clip?

The thing is, I want to be able to zoom in and out of a movie clip, which has some buttons on top, but the buttons have to be placed in specific parts of the movie clip. When the clip is resized, the buttons don't change their position/scale in relation to the clip. Help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you nest the buttons on the timeline of the movieclip you are scaling they should scale with it because they are parts of that symbol.